# Vba Excel ADODB pre-load in cash dataset to query faster a big Access dataset 500000 rows

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

Good afternoon
I have an issue: speed in Excel retrieving data from Access external database
(47 sec. --> I want to reach 3 seconds)
Excel 2010
Access 2000

Code at the opening event I open I run this macro:

```
'I define connection and dataset as public
Public conn As ADODB.Connection
Public mrs As ADODB.Recordset
Public cmd As ADODB.Command

Public DBPath As String
Public strConn As String
Public strSQL As String

Public Sub preloadDataset()

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set mrs = New ADODB.Recordset

DBPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Exported.mdb"

    With conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data source=" & DBPath
        .Open
    End With


Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Database_5000Rows] WHERE "PrNameHelp" = ? AND "ScCompHelp" LIKE ""%?%""

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.Prepared = True

        'MANUAL creation of parameters
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("PrNameHelp", adLongVarChar, adParamInput)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("ScCompHelp", adLongVarChar, adParamInput)

End sub
```

The main macro:

```
Public Sub ADO_retrieve_Ext_file()

cmd("PrNameHelp") = str01
cmd("ScCompHelp") = str02

cmd.Execute

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset mrs
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End sub
```

In the closing event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
'**********************
    ''Close Recordset
    mrs.Close
    ''Close Connection
    conn.Close
    Set mrs = Nothing
    Set Conn = Nothing
'**********************

End sub
```

How can I define parameters taking care of SQL correct string for Access ?
Is it the correct method using parameters or it is better to upload in RAM the whole database?

Thank you 
Enrico

Comment: You may also receive some good, focused help on this subject by posting on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) .

Comment: While you have provided good specifics on your issue, this topic is so broad that the first thing I would want to know is whether you are using SSD or spindle drives and the questions only multiply from there.

Comment: Not using a solid state drive

Comment: Do you need to retrieve just one row, only a few rows, most of the rows, or all the rows from the table?

Comment: can you post all the code please that you are using for the procedure

Comment: @HansUp I need all rows sometimes when the userform have all empty fields (is searching for ""), some rows from the whole database when one of the 2 fiels are filled up.

Comment: @Mark Horner the rest of the code is simple: copyfromrecordset . I will add inside the code ok?!

Comment: Fields are in Access less than 255 characters (are not memo fields and for this are indexed and for this reason also parameters can be used as suggested

Comment: Any clue in here? Thank you so much for your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: programmatically indexed the first column of the table in Access

Answer (score 0):

When copying your data to the sheet, try to avoid update it until you finish. Use:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = true
```

Comment: SOLVED: programmatically indexed the first column of the table in Access : 6 secs reached